# Обход CORS policy

Tags: javascript, http

**Как обойти CORS policy?** У меня должен быть **локальный** сайт (его не будет в интернете), который я потом буду использовать в приложении. Проблема в том, что я не могу **импортировать и экспортировать** модули js. Пишет:

> Access to script at 'file:///.../scripts/framework/router.js' from
> origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests
> are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
> chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: Ну тогда просто запустите локальный сайт по локальному адресу [http://localhost](http://localhost), наверное?

Comment: @andreymal, проблема в том, что дальше я буду использовать сайт в мобильном приложении и там такое не прокатит.

Comment: Как именно вы будете его использовать? Почему не прокатит?

Comment: @andreymal, говорю же, будет использоваться в ПРИЛОЖЕНИИ (WebView). Я же не буду писать свой локальный сервер, допустим, для андройд, чтобы мой сайт там запустился.

Comment: Ну значит сразу проверяйте работоспособность в этом самом приложении и в этом самом WebView